# Fatal error: Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in {address}

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I use of [this](http://www.phpro.org/downloads/mvc-0.0.3.tar.gz) mvc. (here is the [documentation](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)). Now I want to create a module for connect to database and run the query. but there is a error:

> **Fatal error:** Cannot access self:: when no class scope is active in {address(in db.class.php)}

What is the problem ??

**db.class.php** (in the model folder)

```
<?php

class db{

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $instance = NULL;


/*
* @return object (PDO)
*
* @access public
*/

public static function getInstance() {

if (!self::$instance) {

    function dataQuery($query, $params) {
    // what kind of query is this?
    $queryType = explode(' ', $query);

    // establish database connection
    try {
        self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spy', USER, PASS);
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        $errorCode = $e->getCode();
    }

    // run query
    try {
        $queryResults = self::$instance->prepare($query);
        $queryResults->execute($params);
        if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
          $results = $queryResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             return $results;
        }
        $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
        $dbh = null; // second step tp close the connection
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        echo $errorMsg.'<br>';
    }
  }
}
return self::$instance;
}

} /*** end of class ***/

?>
```

**init.php** (in the includes )

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
    $filename = strtolower($class_name) . '.class.php';
    $file = __SITE_PATH . '/model/' . $filename;

    if (file_exists($file) == false)
    {
        return false;
    }
  include ($file);
}

 /*** a new registry object ***/
 $registry = new registry;

 /*** create the database registry object ***/
  $registry->db = db::getInstance();
?>
```

**index.php:** (in the controller folder)

```
<?php
Class indexController Extends baseController {

public function index() {

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

define('USER', 'root');
define('PASS', '');


function findKitByMfgPrice($mfg, $price) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `prod_name` LIKE ? AND `prod_price` > ?";
    $params = array($mfg, $price);
    $results = dataQuery($query, $params);
     return $results;
}

$mfg = '%Mobeius%';
$price = 34.95;
$kitsByMfgPrice = findKitByMfgPrice($mfg, $price);
echo '<pre>';

$welcome = $kitsByMfgPrice;


    /*** set a template variable ***/
        $this->registry->template->welcome = $welcome;
    /*** load the index template ***/
        $this->registry->template->show('index1');
}
?>
```

Comment: Don't you have the line number of the error ? By the way you are declaring a function `dataQuery` into the function `getInstance`. I think, the problem comes from here... It makes the function not part of the class `db`, so `self` has no sense...

Comment: @Random I don't understand your mean.

Comment: @Random exactly !! the problem comes from function `dataQuery` ! how can I solve it ? If I remove function `dataQuery`. I can't send argument ! and I can't call it in the `index.php`

Comment: You method `getInstance` has no sense... The purpose is to make a new object `db` if none already exists... so what should be inside the `if` is a call to a constructor... not the declaration of a function... how did `dataQuery` came where it is ? It may be a public function (not static !), declared after the `getInstance` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database should be used this way :
db.php :

```
class db{

/*** Declare instance ***/
private static $instance = NULL;

/*
* @return object (PDO)
*
* @access public
*/

public static function getInstance() {

    if (!self::$instance) {
        // establish database connection
        try {
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=spy', USER, PASS);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            self::$instance->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            $errorCode = $e->getCode();
        }
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public static function dataQuery($query, $params) {
    // what kind of query is this?
    $queryType = explode(' ', $query);
    // run query
    try {
        $queryResults = self::getInstance()->prepare($query);
        $queryResults->execute($params);
        if($queryResults != null && 'SELECT' == $queryType[0]) {
            $results = $queryResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $results;
        }
        $queryResults = null; // first of the two steps to properly close
        $dbh = null; // second step tp close the connection
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $errorMsg = $e->getMessage();
        echo $errorMsg.'<br>';
    }

} /*** end of class ***/
```

and to use it, in your index :

```
function findKitByMfgPrice($mfg, $price) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `prod_name` LIKE ? AND `prod_price` > ?";
    $params = array($mfg, $price);
    $results = db::dataQuery($query, $params);
    return $results;
}
```

this should be a good start. But It still looks strange... the `dataQuery` methods is misplaced, it should not be part of the db class, it should be a local method of your index I think... Must think about it...

Comment: just one thing: why you are used `return self::$instance;` and then use `$queryResults = self::getInstance()->prepare($query);` ?? there is not a optimized manner ?

Comment: @stack When using `self::$instance`, you have to be sure it is defined... The only way to be sure it is defined if calling `getInstance` to get it. Doing this, even if it doesn't exist yet, it will be created for you, without worrying about it. So inside the `getInstance` method is the only place where we can use `self::$instance`, because it is the only place where we check its existance.

Comment: do you have free time for a moment ?! can you chat with me [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82974/room-for-stack-and-random) ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm off for today, I'm back on Monday, let's take a room then, post a comment here on Monday morning to meet :)

Comment: why you are used `db::getInstance();` in index,php ? there is a file named init.php that is contained `$registry->db = db::getInstance();`. now can you tell me how can I use `$registry->db` in the controller (index.php) ?

Comment: the `$registry->db` is useless... you can use it, it will be exactly the same DB, so you will be able to do the same things... but it'll always be safer to use `db::getInstance()->xxx`... the only point is that if you use `$registry->db` it may be harder to debug... your website must use the same "pattern" everywhere. So `$registry->db` everywhere, and no `db::getInstance()`, or vis versa... it is highly unrecommanded to use both, for easy-to-read matter... And I would recommand not to use `$registry->db`

Comment: @stack still want a chat ?

Comment: is it possible you give me the name of your skype account ? because if I have your ID it would be powerful and relaxing

Comment: @stack I can't, all I can do is a SO chat :)

Comment: ah alright, then I don't need to chat now, but I'm sure that I will need to it later. thanks